# Data.Proxy in servant's public API (why Proxy with ScopedTypeVariables doesn't work)

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking

I'm excited about [servant](http://haskell-servant.github.io/), and I'm ok with its internal typelevel magic as long as it doesn't gets in the way, and the only thing that confuses me is its use of a [type-proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Proxy.html) in public API. Here's the [code](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/blob/master/servant-server/src/Servant/Server.hs#L109):

```
serve :: HasServer layout => Proxy layout -> Server layout -> Application
serve p server = toApplication (runRouter (route p (return (RR (Right server)))))
```

As I understand, type-proxies are fairly simple thing and are needed to carry a type when you don't have a value with that type. So why to pass a proxy carrying layout type when there is already layout type in Server's type parameter? I've tried cloning servant's repo and changing code to this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

serve :: forall layout . HasServer layout => Server layout -> Application
serve server = toApplication (runRouter (route p (return (RR (Right server)))))
  where
    p :: Proxy layout
    p  = Proxy
```

And surprisingly to me this fails to compile (telling something about layout type mismatch). But why, shouldn't my local p have the same layout type as server (with ScopedTypeVariables turned on)?

Comment: Executable example, please.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, the question is basically why (and in what cases) the local same-type-carrying p isn't the same as if we pass it externally as parameter. I'm sorry, but as I don't understand what's going on, I don't know how to reproduce this with simpler cases without ' git clone https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant.git '.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type families are not injective, and behind `Server` there's one. So if you pass a `Server MyAPI` to this function, GHC won't be able to conclude `layout = MyAPI`. We unfortunately really need a `Proxy` in there. Even if we had injective type families, that wouldn't help:

```
type API1 = Get '[JSON] User
type API2 = Post '[JSON] User
```

These two APIs are such that `Server API1 = Server API2` but `API1 /= API2`, which actually shows us that `Server` **must not** be injective. The easiest way to disambiguate the API type we want to target is the `Proxy`. On the other hand, that's quite often the only thing our APIs ask for in the various servant packages.

Comment: For a longer explanation of type families and injectivity, see https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Injectivity.2C_type_inference.2C_and_ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

`Server` isn't a type constructor, it's a type synonym for the `ServerT` associated type in the [`HasServer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.4.3.1/docs/Servant-Server-Internal.html) class. Therefore `layout` occurring in `Server layout` doesn't disambiguate the `HasServer` constraint. We can only resolve the `Server layout` type if we already have a `HasServer layout` instance.

Comment: I've begun to think Haskell's designers erred in capitalizing type synonyms (and therefore type families). They violate the useful law that everything that starts with a capital letter is a constructor. Their choice allows the dubious shorthand of omitting `forall` at the top level, which hardly seems worth the ambiguity.